# How to flatten out a curve based on the dot product to be linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-curves, spherical-coordinates, angle, spherical-trigonometry

I am interpreting a value based on the amount an object is "facing" a wall in a performance critical computer simulation. I take the dot product between the object's forward vector and the negated normal of the wall, so if it's facing the wall 100%, the function **returns 1,** and if 100% parallel to the wall, it **returns 0.**

I want to scale another value based on the return value of this function. I want it to scale **linearly** within the domain of this function from 100% facing, to 100% parallel.

But as you know, the dot product is based on cosine, so the range of return values will be **non-linear.** When the vector is 50% facing and 50% parallel, it will return something around 0.7, but I want it to return 0.5. If it is 75% facing and 25% parallel, it should return 0.75.

I know this involves slerping, but dont know how to apply it.

*** I already have the dot product, so I would like to avoid further calculations, like arrcos to get the angle, which is expensive.**

*** This is not a quaternion situation either. I just want to distribute the output range of the dotproduct linearly between 0 and 1.**

Please help, thanks.

Comment: You want to scale linearly with the angle, right? So $45^\circ$ is mapped to $0.5$? Then you are literally asking for the arccos of the dot product.

Comment: @rahul so you mean (arccos(dotProduct(a, b)) / 90degrees) right?

Comment: Yes, or rather 1 - that. You can't avoid the fact that what you're looking for is essentially arccos, but if it's really too expensive for you, you could replace it with a precomputed lookup table or something like that.